# Trigger a keyup event function on meeting a certain condition in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code where the user when he/she presses `NumpadEnter` key, a certain function triggers:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.code === "NumpadEnter") {   
         //some logic here    
    }
}
```

Now I want to trigger this `keyup` function when a certain condition is met:

```
if(flag == true){
    //trigger the keyup listener
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: So what would you want the `event` argument to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trigger the event. Instead place the logic in a separate function that both the event handler and the other code will call:

```
function performAction() {
   // logic here
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.code === "NumpadEnter") {   
         performAction(); 
    }
}

// Now I want to trigger this keyup function when a certain condition is met:

if (flag == true){
    performAction();
}
```

Comment: Is this not going to execute the perfornAction() anyways regardless of whether the flag is true or false?

Comment: @Tiberius, why would you think that?

Comment: What happens when the keyup event fires?

Comment: The function is executed. I don't think the asker wanted a change in that behaviour, but wanted to have an *additional* call made from other code on certain conditions.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I didn't get it right but, they are saying "Now I want to trigger this keyup function when a certain condition is met:"

Answer (score -1):

Put the keyup listener inside the flag checker. Then, pass a function to handle the event. Have that function as shown here:

```js
function handleEvent(event) {
    if (event.code === "NumpadEnter") {   
         //some logic here    
    }
}

if(flag == true){
    //trigger the keyup listener
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleEvent)
}
```

Comment: This will not do what the comment says: it will not trigger the keyup listener. It will only *bind* the listener.